# TeXShop indentation when inserting environment

Tags: texshop

In TeXShop I create an `equation` environment by typing the word "equation" and then pressing CMD-B. This results in the following, where "|" is my cursor:

```
\begin{equation}
 |
\end{equation}
```

The cursor is initially indented by a single space. I would much rather it be indented by a tab character. (Or even better, four spaces, as long as the tab key could also be reconfigured to insert four spaces.)

Is there a way to change this behaviour in the way I would like? I couldn't find anything about it in the preferences.

Comment: Avoid TAB in TeX documents.

Comment: @egreg just out of curiosity, why? (The only reason for wanting to use tab characters is that, as far as I can tell, the tab key cannot be configured to insert spaces in TeXShop.)

Comment: 30+ year experience…

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do this using TeXShop's Command Completion and the Command Completion file can easily be edited. Using Command Completion you would enter

```
beq
```

at the beginning of a line and then press the trigger key (ESC by default) to get

```
\begin{equation}
|•|
\end{equation}•
```

where |•| is a selected `bullet' (called a Mark here). Then you can simply type the equation and that Mark will be replaced by youe text. There is a command that jumps to the next bullet and selects it (Ctl-Cmd-F) so you can easily get to the end of the environment. Please see the Help->TeXShop Tips and Tricks document for more information.

Oh... the Command Completion file can be edited so you can can change the formatting of the commands to your taste.

Answer (score 0):

A self-answer: this is easy to achieve by editing the AppleScript. Go to Macros -> Open Macro Editor and then look for "Insert Begin/End". Look for the line

```
set environment to begin_environment & linefeed & " " & linefeed & end_environment
```

about half way through and change it to

```
set environment to begin_environment & linefeed & "\t" & linefeed & end_environment
```

and that's it.

However, the macro still doesn't respect the indentation of any surrounding environment. Fixing that is a separate question that I've asked at [Getting TeXShop to indent begin/end properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699018/getting-texshop-to-indent-begin-end-properly).