# Getting TeXShop to indent begin/end properly

Tags: texshop

I don't know if this question is on topic here, since in a way it's really an AppleScript question - but it's also about TeXShop, which is part of the TeXLive distribution, so it seems worth a go. Suggestions for a better place to ask are welcome.

I often use TeXShop's "Insert Begin/End" macro, which is invoked by CMD-B. If I type `equation` on a blank line and press CMD-B it turns it into

```
\begin{equation}
 |
\end{equation}
```

where the `|` represents the cursor.

The problem is that I like to indent my code, and this macro doesn't respect that. If I type the following (where `|` is the cursor)

```
\begin{proof}
    % ...
    equation|
\end{proof}
```

and press CMD-B I get

```
\begin{proof}
    % ...
\begin{equation}
 |
\end{equation}
\end{proof}
```

What I really want is

```
\begin{proof}
    % ...
    \begin{equation}
        |
    \end{equation}
\end{proof}
```

with everything indented to the same level that the word `equation` was originally, and the contents of the environment indented with an additional tab character.

TeXShop's macros use AppleScript, so in principle it should be possible to achieve this behaviour by editing the macro. But I am not an AppleScript whizz and so I'm wondering if there is anyone around who is, or who has already done this.

Here is the current code of the Insert Begin/End macro:

```
--Applescript direct
-- Script to insert a begin/end block
-- Ramon Figueroa-Centeno March 10, 2009

tell application "TeXShop"
    
    -- The linefeed character.
    set linefeed to ASCII character 10
    
    set TeX_delimiters to {linefeed, return, tab} & characters of ¬
        " {}[](),:;.\\|/?!<>`'\"@#$%^~&-+=" as list
    
    set the front_document to the front document
    -- set the front_document to document #DOCUMENTNAME#
    
    -- The whole text of the document
    set whole_document to (the text of the front_document) as string
    
    -- The offset of the selection
    set selection_offset to offset of the selection of the front_document
    
    repeat until (selection_offset = 0) or (character selection_offset of ¬
        the whole_document is in TeX_delimiters)
        set selection_offset to selection_offset - 1
    end repeat
    set the offset of the selection of the front_document to selection_offset
    
    set selection_length to 0
    
    try
        set next_character to character (selection_offset + selection_length + 1) of ¬
            the whole_document
        repeat until (next_character is in TeX_delimiters)
            set selection_length to selection_length + 1
            try
                set next_character to character (selection_offset + selection_length + 1) of ¬
                    the whole_document
            on error
                -- reached the end of the document
                exit repeat
            end try
        end repeat
    end try
    set the length of the selection of the front_document to selection_length
    
    -- The selection is empty, so stop
    if selection_length = 0 then
        beep
        return
    end if
    
    set environment_name to the content of the selection of the front_document
    set begin_environment to "\\begin{" & environment_name & "}"
    set end_environment to "\\end{" & environment_name & "}"
    set environment to begin_environment & linefeed & " " & linefeed & end_environment
    set insertion_point to (count of begin_environment) + selection_offset + 3
    
    -- determine if we are the beginning of a line
    set at_the_beginning to ((selection_offset = 0) or (character selection_offset of ¬
        the whole_document is in {linefeed, return}))
    
    -- determine if we are at the end of a line
    -- (since we do not know if we are at the end of the document
    -- we use a "try" to avoid having to count the characters of the document)
    set at_the_end to false
    try
        if character (selection_offset + selection_length + 1) of ¬
            the whole_document is in {linefeed, return} then
            set at_the_end to true
        end if
    on error
        set at_the_end to true
    end try
    
    if at_the_beginning and at_the_end then
        -- say "at the beginning and the end"
        set the content of the selection of the front_document to ¬
            environment
        set the offset of the selection of the front_document to ¬
            insertion_point - 1
    else if at_the_beginning then
        -- say "at the beginning"
        set the content of the selection of the front_document to ¬
            environment & linefeed
        set the offset of the selection of the front_document to ¬
            insertion_point
    else if at_the_end then
        -- say "at the end"
        set the content of the selection of the front_document to ¬
            linefeed & environment
        set the offset of the selection of the front_document to ¬
            insertion_point
    else
        -- say "at the middle"
        set the content of the selection of the front_document to ¬
            linefeed & environment & linefeed
        set the offset of the selection of the front_document to ¬
            insertion_point
    end if
end tell
```

P.S. I asked a similar previous question, [TeXShop indentation when inserting environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652014/texshop-indentation-when-inserting-environment), but that was only about changing the indentation of the text inside the environment, not the environment itself. I solved that question already and will post a self-answer there.